# Creating .desktop files to use on the "Open with other application" tab

Tags: nautilus, customization, default-programs

I am looking for the specs necessary to build a `.desktop` file to be used in Ubuntu 11.10.

Many terminal applications or even GUI application do not show on `Open with other application` tab anymore and I want to create a `.desktop` file that makes that application be listed on the list again.

I know that you can create a `.desktop` file and place it in `~/.local/share/applications` but I do not know what all those settings mean.

Is there a guide that allows me to customize my `.desktop` files to my needs?

Comment: If you don't need to remember thast association, this script could be handy: https://github.com/gecos-team/openwith

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An example of a `.desktop` file to select vim terminal editor for your files in the `Open with other application` dialog is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Vim Text Editor (Console)
Comment=Edit text files in a console using Vim
Exec=vim %u
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/vim.svg
Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=true
```

Save this as `~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop` and the application will be automatically shown on `Open with other application` to be selected as default application.

The options for the `.desktop` files are many but its important to know what they mean.

[nautilus-actions.org](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/?q=node/377) supplies a very good guide and explanations for creating your `.desktop` files and all the possible parameters that you can use on them so if you have any doubts about creating a special `.desktop` file you can visit the site and look at the examples there.

Comment: +1. This is what I was looking for Bruno. Thanks.

Comment: As of 2023 the site nautilus-actions.org does not exist.  The specification for the .desktop file format can be found [at freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/).

Answer (score 4):

When an installed app shows up on the r. click > open with but not on the r. click > properties > open with list it's usually because of the Exec= line in the app's .desktop

Two ways around - 
Just add the apps .desktop to an appropriate line in the [Default Applications] section of

~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

If the line already exists then you'd just replace the current .desktop with the intended app's .desktop

In the case of .tex the line would be

```
text/x-tex=
```

The other solution would be to open the app's .desktop in a text editor and add to the end of the Exec= line a space  %letter

Not knowing your app I'd say that either %f or %U are generally ok.

Ex. using gedit to show what i mean

```
Exec=gedit %U
```

This will then allow the app to show up in the r. click > properties ... list