# How can I add wine programs to the right click context menu?

Tags: wine, menu, microsoft-office, playonlinux

How can someone automatically add wine programs (such as Microsoft Office) to the right click context menu? In my case specifically the software is installed via play on linux.

For example, when a user right clicks on a *.doc file, they have the choice of "Open with Libre Office" and "Open with Microsoft Word".

***P.S** I have done this before on a previous installation but I can't remember exactly how.*

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine may be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a previous version of Ubuntu (not 11.10) you can right click the file, select Properties and in the Open With tab you can search the option to write you custom application. For example, if you know Microsoft Word can open a doc using this line (I don't use msword so I don't really know if the follow command will work, it's just an example):

```
wine msword mydoc
```

then, you put that line in the custom application box.

If you're using 11.10 that's not possible ([why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72957/file-application-asociation-using-a-custom-command-is-gone)), so you should look [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab). That way you can add any application to the Open With option, including wine.

Hope it helps.

Best regards,