# How can I remove / change the "Open With" list?

Tags: nautilus, mime-type

I have one problem. Just look at image:
[image: My Problem]

So I want to remove one of Dev-C++ IDE and Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector (I've tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio and it doesn't works,and one of the Dev-C++ IDE too). But I don't know how to change that list. I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enter the contextual menu of the file and go to the `Properties` of it. Then, go to `Open with` tab, right click on the application you want to remove and click on `Forget association`.

Comment: This does not work for wine applications.

Comment: @To Do, this may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74266/how-can-i-add-wine-programs-to-the-right-click-context-menu

Comment: There is no `Forget association` button in Ubuntu 14.04 (or I can't find it)

Comment: @becko I don't know what kind of patched version does Ubuntu  use of nautilus. But the `Forget association` is definitely there in Nautilus 3.12/3.14. Are you sure you are **right** clicking into the application you want to forget?

Comment: This doesn't work for 15.04 Vivid Vervet either

Answer (score 5):

Goto `~/.local/share/applications`, edit the file `mimeapps.list`:

In [Added Associations] section, you will find your file extension, something like this:

```
application/epub=FBReader.desktop;<another apps.desktop>
```

Which means there are two apps will be shown in "Open with..." menu when right click an `epub` file, identify the one for `Dev-C++ IDE` in your case and remove it.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me remove the Wine Internet Explorer/notepad/wordpad options from my "open with" list. Just go to that folder and delete all the wine-extension-*.desktop.

Comment: In my case, the offending associations are not defined in that file.

Answer (score 1):

My Ubuntu 14.04LTS does not have a mimeapps.list.

I solved this issue creating a new file in `/usr/share/applications` called `mimeapps.list` with the following content:

```
[Added Associations]
inode/directory=audacious.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;
[Removed Associations]
inode/directory=baobab.desktop;nautilus.desktop;nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
```

In this case, the configuration will remove applications from the context menu of any folder. I got most of the information from here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications

---

UPDATE

I have also found `mimeapps.list` in `~/.local/share/applications`. I guess if you add the same lines to that file, it will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus, Thunar et al. take their information from `mimeapps.list` files¹.

So the solution is to edit `.config/mimeapps.list` and/or `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Add entries in the `[Removed Associations]` section like so:

```
[Removed Associations]
application/xml=firefox.desktop;wine-extension-xml.desktop;
image/png=shutter.desktop;wine-extension-png.desktop;
image/jpeg=shutter.desktop;wine-extension-jpe.desktop;wine-extension-jfif.desktop;  
image/svg+xml=shutter.desktop;wine-notepad.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;gitkraken.desktop;gimp.desktop;wine-extension-xml.desktop;yed.desktop;
application/xml=yed.desktop;
```

Look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#Format) for some details.

You might have to do some digging to find the correct `.desktop` files; note, for instance, that multiple `wine-*.desktop` files declared the same application for `image/jpeg`.

---

1. The different `mimeinfo.cache` files are populated by `update-desktop-database` from the `.desktop` files you have around. I don't know how those relate to `mimeapps.list`; see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/992582/69674).