# How to change "Open With" with force and fury?

Tags: file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change Open With list (remove somthing or change)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-change-open-with-list-remove-somthing-or-change)

This question is obviously NOT a duplicate as actual reading more than one sentence will show.

---

Every [too often] in a [forever] there will be problems with the `Open With` context menu item. I've seen it changed around a **lot**, and it's still horrible. *Applauds*

Now once again I've got a corrupt item that I want to replace with the correct item that is installed cleanly into the Application menu. I updated a program, and although all traces of the old are gone, the context-menu insists on living in the past. I cannot for the love of me find a fix.

What did I do? I installed the (awesome and overshadowing all the other excuses for image viewers for Linux out there) [XnViewMP](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewforum.php?f=60) image viewer. Then sometime later, I updated it.

The old one was started with `/usr/local/share/XnViewMP/xnview.sh`.
The new one with `/usr/sbin/xnview`

I tried the basic FAQs out there.

- There is the `Open With -> More -> Show Other Applications -> XnView` that just gives me an error about `/usr/local/share/XnViewMP/xnview.sh` not existing. I know!
- There is the `Open With` tab in the `File Properties` that has the option to forget an association, but that doesn't do anything. I can reset the association. Then I can add XnView again, but it has the same problem.

  - To the idiots that closed this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-change-open-with-list-remove-somthing-or-change): **The solution there is exactly what I am talking about here!** It's different and not applicable here. You ruined a perfectly good question! Thanks a lot.

**I just need to know *where* this little `Open With` system gets its information***, use a hammer and a blowtorch on whatever files it uses, and manually enter the same path that the Application Menu is clever enough to use.

I've got the hammer and the blowtorch. **Now where are the files I am looking for?** *

*) I have marked the most important sentences to help people understand that this is NOT a duplicate question of the one it's marked for.

---

**Answered my own question**

1. /usr/share/applications/*.desktop

   - Global (root) applications, you cann add default mimetypes here:
   - MimeType=image/bmp;image/gif;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;image/png;image/jp2;image/jpeg2000;image/jpx;
2. /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

   - Contains these global associations in a single file, which is created from all the `.desktop` files from time to time.
3. ~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop

   - Local (user) applications
4. ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

   - Contains these local associations in a single file, which is created from all the `.desktop` files, plus customizations from the `Open` With dialog.

In my case, I had to manually change all mentions of `userapp-xnview.sh-C2F5D4.desktop` to `XnView.desktop`. **Resetting the associations didn't work** and the **correct app never showed up**. Which is both **a bug** and **completely different from the duplicate you closed this question for.**

Log off and on again before it takes effect.

Comment: This does not seem to be a duplicate of the suggested question. Manually adding application (like making Adobe Reader the default pdf reader: ```application/pdf=acroread.desktop```) in the  ```~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list``` file is pretty neat. Thanks!