# How to remove duplicate element from context menu?

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm, context-menu

When I right click on a folder - I see double element "file" - open in Nautilus (installed on my Lubuntu).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo mv nautilus.desktop nautilus.disabled
```

Afterwards restart PCManFM

What you are doing here is renaming the file `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` - you could also delete it, the name you use doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thank you, it work. And I have menu item "File Manager PCManFM" - you know how I can remove this also? If I make click on folder - it opening in PCManFM and I don't need this menu item.

Comment: `sudo mv pcmanfm.desktop pcmanfm.disabled` (like above) will get rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunately it also removes the application from the Dash!

Comment: I posted a solution that does not removes it from the dash here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-remove-change-the-open-with-list/567254#567254

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cd /usr/share/nautilus/ui
sudo cp nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml.bak
sudo gedit nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml
```

Remove duplicates, and then

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: bash: cd: /usr/share/nautilus/ui: No such file or directory

Comment: You didn't see that he is using PCManFM as file manager (Lubuntu!).