# How do mimeinfo.cache files relate to mimeapps.list?

Tags: .desktop, mime-type, xdg

The different `mimeinfo.cache` files are populated by `update-desktop-database` from the `.desktop` files you have around.

However, file browsers and such seem to use `mimeapps.list` files. Manipulating those can be arduous, in particular if some app was greedy and registered itself with many Mime types I don't want to see it on.

Ideally, one would change (or override) the `.desktop` files of the offending applications and the aggregated lists would be updated accordingly. How does one do that?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the desktop file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`
and modify as needed.

Just remove some entries in MimeType

```
...
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;
...
```

Afterwards restart session.