# When does /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache get updated and can I protect it?

Tags: apt, default-programs, mime-type

I find it really irritating that some applications (e.g. pdfshuffler and calibre) end up a higher priority in `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` than my desired application for PDFs (okular).

I manually edit this file from time to time to remove undesirable applications, but it sometimes seems to reset, and my undesirable applications end up being at the front of the list and thus used to open PDFs.

I suspect this happens when packages get updated, but I'm not sure. Is this the case?

Otherwise, when is this file getting updated?

And can I protect existing settings so as to prevent applications from stealing priority?

Comment: eh. why would you even consider editing the system wide mimeinfo.cache? why not use the user specific cache to overrule the system one?

Comment: a) because this is the file I first encountered when trying to solve this problem a while ago and I looked no further at the time, b) because maybe I want system-wide settings

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
this file is updated every time the system is rebooted
rewriting it is useless.

better copy the file `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
to this path `~/.local/share/applications/` (if there is no `applications` folder, just create it)

and now only edit this file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` for the changes to take effect

[How do mimeinfo.cache files relate to mimeapps.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992582/how-do-mimeinfo-cache-files-relate-to-mimeapps-list) - similar answer to question

hope this answer helps you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234213)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have taken note of your comments, thank you.