# Can I meddle with xdg-setting to open a popup asking me with which browser to open a link I just clicked?

Tags: browser, default, default-programs, xdg, xdg-open

I work on multiple browsers simultaneously. I wish that every time I open a link from outside a browser( let's say from a pfd) a window or a terminal pops up to ask me which browser to use.

Is there any way to configure xdg-settings to make that happen? or any other way?

If there's no way, what should I read and understand to code my own thing? 
Thanks

Comment: My initial reaction is to associate links to your own script which uses `zenity` or `yad` to prompt with chrome or Firefox, etc.

Comment: That's a good way to do.
Isn't there something already included with xdg that does the thing?
I remember that clicking on magnet links from a browser prompts an xdg dialog.

Comment: Related: [File / Application association using a custom command is gone?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72957/37165) mentions `mimeopen` that has option to ask which application to run. Not an XDG tool, but good starting point to write own script.