# How do I manually associate a program to a file type in 11.10?

Tags: file-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating .desktop files to use on the “Open with other application” tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab)

The interface for associating a file type to a particular application has changed in 11.10 due to the introduction of GNOME 3.  In previous versions, if I went to file properties, and went to the Open With tab, it would be possible to browse /usr/bin for the program I wanted.
Now, the Open With tab only provides a list of applications, and that list is not complete.  If the application I want is not on the list, I don't know how to change the file association.  For example, I want .tex files to open with TeXmaker, not Gedit.  I get an 'Open with TeXmaker' option in the right-click menu, but TeXmaker is not on the list of programs I can permanently associate to the program.  I'd also like to associate .deb files to gdebi-gtk because I don't like waiting forever for Software Centre to start.