# How do I set SQLite data browser as the default application for .sqlite3 files?

Tags: 11.10, default-programs, sqlite

When I try to open a .sqlite3 file, I get the following error:

```
There is no application installed for SQLite3 database files
```

When trying to select a default application, the SQLite database browser is not listed, despite it being installed.

Also, because the .sqlite3 file does not have a default application, it does not show up in the File Browser within gedit, making things pretty confusing.

How do I set up the default application?

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab) and follow the guide to create your own application launcher. It will then be included on the list so you can select it.

Comment: @BrunoPereira would you consider adding this as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention by Bruno Pereira in a comment on your question you need to create an application launcher for SQlite Database Browser.

To do this open a text editor such as Gedit and create a text document with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=SQLite Database Browser
Comment=Create, Edit and Modify SQLite database files
Exec=sqlitebrowser %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=true
```

Once you have done this name the file sqlitebrowser.desktop and save the file to `~/.local/share/applications`

Once you have done this navigate to a .sqlite3 and right click on it, select **Open with Other Application**

[image]

Then select **Show other applications** and scroll down to select SQlite database Browser from the list and it'll now be the default application to open .sqlite files.

Comment: Just a doubt, the MymeType would not be "application/x-sqlite3"? 
My doubt is due to the info in http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/DB_(SQLite)

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to work on 13.04 but I had to use NoDisplay=false.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=SQLite Database Browser
Comment=Create, Edit and Modify SQLite database files
Exec=sqlitebrowser %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=false
```

This will add to "right click > open with" and "properties > open with"