# Create a file type association for my Truecrypt volumes

Tags: truecrypt, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating .desktop files to use on the “Open with other application” tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab)

i have installed truecrypt
in windows tc extensions are aasociated with truecrypt
my question is 
how do i make my ubuntu 11.10 system associate *.tc extension to open with truecrypt.

also the app opens just fine but is there any way to open it only after u enter password and not during the mounting process.
just like synaptic...

Comment: You can create a .desktop file containing the command you use to open the file following the guide linked.