# How do I set IDLE as the default editor for Python scripts?

Tags: 11.10, python, default-programs, idle-python

I would like to set IDLE as the default editor for python scripts, but when I click on "open with application" and hit the dropdown to show more applications it isn't an option.

Here's exactly what I am doing...

1. right-click on .py file on my desktop.
2. Right click on properties.
3. Click on the Open with tab.

There is no "Use a custom command" option. The same thing happens when I right click on the file and select "open with other application".

Do you of any way I could set this up?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? In 11.04 you can browse to arbitrary program location in "Open with" dialog. For 11.10 I think you can do same with "Properties" dialog

Comment: I am using 11.04, but IDLE is showing up in the open with other app dialouge.

Comment: OK then, tick on "Remember this application" and select IDLE from "Open with" dialog

Comment: Sorry, made a typo.  *IDLE is NOT showing up in the open with other app dialouge box.

Comment: Well, when you select "Other application" a dialog will open. You'll notice at the bottom a roll on/off label "Use a custom command". Just browse then to location of IDLE and tick on "Remember this application" if you want to make it default

Comment: I saw a screenshot of that online, but I can't replicate it.  Here's exactly what I am doing... 1. right-click on .py file on my desktop.  2.  Right click on properties.  3.  Click on the Open with tab.  There is no "Use a custom command" option.  The same thing happens when I right click on the file and select "open with other application".

Comment: Are you sure you are using 11.04? In 11.10 "Custom command" option is on other place

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating .desktop files to use on the "Open with other application" tab](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab)

Comment: Have a look on the link above to create a launcher for your IDE.

Comment: Turns out I am using 11.10.  I'm working at getting the .desktop file to work.  Shame they didn't have this functionality by default.  It seems like a pretty big oversight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't mention which idle package you are using, let's assume "Idle". If using "Idle3" then use `idle3.desktop` below. If using "Idle(using Python-2.7)" then use `idle-python2.7.desktop`

There are 2 things preventing you from finding idle in the context menus -

First none of the idle .desktops have a MimeType= line in them, that's why Idle doesn't show in the r. click > open with ... menu

Additionally  - only .desktops whose Exec= line ends with a  %letter will show in the r. click > properties context menu, even if they show up in the above 'open with' menu

So in this case easiest to just do this - first add to the open with menu

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

In the [Added Associations] section look for this line

text/x-python=

If there then add this to the end

```
idle.desktop;
```

If not there then just add

```
text/x-python=idle.desktop;
```

Idle should now be available in the open with menu, if not log out/in

While there, in the [Default Applications] section look for the same line & replace the .desktop as such, if not there just add the line ( no `;` is used in the Defaults section

```
text/x-python=idle.desktop
```

If Idle doesn't show up as the default, even after a restart then you'll need to 'force' it. I'd prefer this way rather than messing with defaults.list

open the .desktop in a root editor

```
 gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/idle.desktop
```

Add a  %f to the end of the line, save - like

```
Exec=/usr/bin/idle -n %f
```

Then ck. again & see if Idle is now the default, do a log out/in if needed.
Once it's added then you can reopen idle.desktop & remove the %f, it should stay as default.
I'm not sure if %f is appropriate for idle, otherwise I'd say you could leave  it

[image]

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 13.04, without reloading session (but maybe just relaunching Nautilus). Great thanks!

Comment: Make sure you put the entry for IDLE under `[Added Associations]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it:

1. Go to a folder that contains a Python file.
2. Right-click on any Python file.
3. Select Properties.
4. Next to the section that says “Opens with”, click the Change button.
5. You may need to select More Options.
6. Click on Look for another app on this PC.
7. Navigate to where you installed Python. For me, that’s the Python34 folder on the C drive.
8. Open Lib
9. Open idlelib
10. Select the idle.bat file.
11. Click Open.
12. Click OK to close out of Properties.
13. Now you can open .py files in IDLE simply by double-clicking on them.

We also have a [video showing how to associate Python files with IDLE](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/02/associate-python-files-with-idle/).