# Cannot change icon for a filetype

Tags: icons, mime-type

I am trying to change the icon for .py file.

I referred:

https://askubuntu.com/a/78645/78407

https://askubuntu.com/a/56725/78407

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes

Still no success in changing the icon of python scripts. They remain like gedit icons.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/nautilus-preview.html) says:

> The file manager creates thumbnails to preview image and video files,
>   and can also preview text files and sound files......The icon for
>   plain text files looks like a piece of paper with text inside. The
>   file manager automatically extracts the first few lines of text from
>   the file and shows it in the icon. You can turn this feature on or
>   off, or turn it on only for files on your computer and local external
>   drives.

To turn off the feature:

- Open `nautilus` and go to **Edit** -> **Preferences**.
- Go to the **Previews** tab and under the **Text Files** section, select the menu for **Show text in icons** and select **Never**.
- Close the Preferences.

[image: Nautilus Preferences]

Now, we come to **changing icons**.

I've *Faenza Icon Theme* installed, so I go to `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/mimetypes/scalable` and there is already an icon file named `text-x-python.svg`, and the same shows for all the `.py` files.

If you've any icon theme installed you should go to the directory for that theme and make the changes, if not you should change the icons in the `/usr/share/icons/gnome` directory.

**Additional Links**: You can read more about **File Manager Preferences** here: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/nautilus-prefs.html.

Comment: Thanks. I already had the icon. Just had to do that "Never" preview thing in nautilus... :)

Comment: Glad it helped.