# Ubuntu 14.04 how to change icon for .docx file type?

Tags: mime-type

I tried many approaches: creating xml in `~/.local/share/mime/packages` and using `assogiate` app, nothing works for me, most guides are outdated and not working for the latest ubuntu build.

the request is very simple, I want to change icon for `*.docx` files, how may I do that?

```
$ grep docx /etc/mime.types 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document         docx
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the icon in your current icon theme. The themes can be found in `/usr/share/icons` or `~/.icons` directory.

Comment: how may i find the exact name of icon file associated with .docx type?

Comment: @AlxKey what theme are you using

Comment: Ambiance - theme

Comment: @AlxKey I think it's here `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes`

Comment: @AlxKey also, see here http://askubuntu.com/a/178466/167115

Comment: how may i find the name of icon for .docx?