# Why can't I easily open .py files with IDLE using right click?

Tags: python, menu, .desktop, file-association, idle-python

I have visited this question and tried everything mentioned with no success:
[How do I set IDLE as default editor for python scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78541/how-do-i-set-idle-as-the-default-editor-for-python-scripts)

> Ubuntu 12.04
>   Python 2.7
>   IDLE(Using Python-2.7)

When I right click a .py file:

- IDLE does not show up in the first menu (the only option is Gedit).
- IDLE does not show up in 'Open With Other Application...' menu
- IDLE does not show up in 'Show other applicatons' menu

I had found the solution to this problem online before, for a previous Ubuntu 12.04 installation, but cannot locate it again.

I imagine this can be fixed through file associations?

Additionally, IDLE windows do not possess an icon and show as a grey box with a '?'.

Comment: I had a similar issue once and can't remember the exact fix, but I think it had to do with making a .desktop launcher and putting the mime-type in it.

Comment: Maybe, it's about bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/1245143 ?? workaround -http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182753&p=12829872#post12829872

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer that worked for me here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1801149

enter the following in terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/idle-python2.7.desktop
```

Add the following to the file:

> MimeType=text/x-python;

Save and close that file, and enter the following in terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Search for "text/x-python=" in the file, or add it if not there, and add the following to the end of it:

> idle-python2.7.desktop;

Worked for me! Cheers.

Comment: I tried exactly this, and it didn't work :(

Comment: What version of linux and python are you using?