# Ubuntu 12.04 How to edit .py file in IDLE without invoking the python shell?

Tags: python, idle-python

First, I followed this answer to modify the file `mimeapps.list`.

[How do I set IDLE as the default editor for Python scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78541/how-do-i-set-idle-as-the-default-editor-for-python-scripts)

It works, but not perfect because everytime I right click .py file--select "Open With IDLE"--a python shell shows alongside the editor.

the following picture show the result of opening two .py files.
[image]

Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Update, as the IDLE appears in right-click menu, I donot run the commands:`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/idle.desktop` and `Exec=/usr/bin/idle -n %f` (no need to do this)

Comment: AFAIK this is the normal IDLE behavior, it even opens the shell on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `/usr/share/applications/idle.desktop` file so at the Exec line it reads:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/idle -en
```

Or the better way would be to copy that file to `~/.local/share/applications` and modify it there similarly, so after an update you won't have to reapply the changes.

But the above will modify IDLE-s opening behaviour even when you open it simply from the Dash/Launcher. If you don't want that, then you would have to make a copy of the `idle.desktop` file in the same directory (`/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`) , name it e.g `idle.other.desktop`, and **modify the Exec line** in that one, and also add a new line with the following content:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Then modify your `mimeapps.list` file, so the `text/x-python=` line reads:

```
text/x-python=idle.other.desktop;
```

Comment: I am not sure what `idle.desktop` is and how to edit it. I only find `IDEL` in /usr/share/applications. and I make a copy `IDLE.other` ,and run command `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/idle.other.desktop`, but only open a blank file, while `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/idle.desktop` can open a file with some setting options in it. why?

Comment: as open idle.other getting a blank file, there is no way for me to add `NoDisplay=true`

Comment: I can see it on your screenshot. There is an icon with the name `IDLE`, that is the `idle.desktop` file, but nautilus hides its extension. If you use terminal to check that directory, you will see. You have to open and edit that file with a text editor.