# How to create Chrome/Chromium web application desktop shortcut?

Tags: 12.10, google-chrome, chromium, shortcuts, webapps

I'm not able to create desktop/Unity short cut for web applications using Chromium/Google Chrome web browser in Ubuntu 12.10.

[image: Chromium web apps]

[image: Ubuntu desktop short cut]

Comment: See if this question helps your cause: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab

Comment: Yes, your comment helps me to create desktop short cut for Google chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research on the internet I found how to create web apps desktop short cuts for Google Chrome/Chromium web browser in Ubuntu 12.10.

**1. Install the application you want from Chrome Webstore and right click on the app icon and select create desktop short-cut.**

[image]

**2. It will creates a desktop short-cut and it will not work on Ubuntu 12.10, we need to edit the

    **chrome-applicationid here-Default.desktop** like file**

[image]

**3. Open the file using Gedit using this command**

```
~$ gedit Desktop/chrome-aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj-Default.desktop
```

(change the file name to yours application ID)

**4. It will open the Gedit text editor and you will need to change first two lines of the text**

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
```

[image]

**to**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
```

**5. Finally save the changes and you will be noticed the change of icon in the desktop and double click on it to run.**

[image]

**Time for playing Angry Birds!**

Comment: Menu/Wrench>Tools>Create App. Done, easier.

Comment: this is the correct one  :) I was able to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Fixing Chromium webapp shortcuts in Lubuntu 12.10
http://computers4christians.org/Chromium-app-shortcut-fix-lubuntu.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window (alt+ctrl+t) and type:

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`

Once you are done installing the above package,run this command to create desktop shortcuts.

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop`

once you enter that command a new window will popup

Let the Type remain as application.

**Name**:Chrome

**command**:`/usr/bin/google-chrome` or you could also browse to the particular location

and click on ok. Your desktop ikon will be created

Comment: This is not what I am looking for exactly. Read the above description carefully. Any way now I am able to create desktop short cut for google chrome apps.